# maximization over a cube, and linear programming

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

Given a compact closed convex set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, its known that for a given $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the following is considered a linear program:
$$
\max_{x \in C} x \cdot y,
$$
where the $\cdot$ represents the dot product.

Instead, we set our objective to be:
$$
\max_{-1 \preceq y \preceq 1} \max_{x \in C} x \cdot y,
$$
where $-1 \preceq y \preceq 1$ means that every entry of $y$ is between $1$ and $-1$.

Is this problem considered to be linear program? And if not, what is it's type?
Can it be solved using any techniques from linear/quadratic/convex optimization?

Please advise and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, your problem can be re-stated as

\begin{equation*}
        \begin{array}{lllr}
        \max & xy\\
        \textrm{subject to } & x &\in &C \\
        & y &\leq &1 \\
        & y &\geq &-1
        \end{array}
\end{equation*}

You are turning your entries $y$ into variables that assumes real numbers between -1 and 1. This can be viewed as a non-linear program since its objective function has a product of two variables.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_programming#Definition

However, if you take a closer look, you can see that there always exists an optimal solution where the values of $y$ are restricted to either 1 or -1 (if $x \geq 0$ then $y=1$, if $x < 0$ then $y=-1$).

So your problem can be rewritten as 
\begin{equation*}
        \begin{array}{lllr}
        \max & \left| \left| x \right| \right|_1\\
        \textrm{subject to } & x &\in &C 
        \end{array}
\end{equation*}

which can be easily linearized in order to find a linear program that models your problem.

Comment: This sounds nice, i was trying to find actually a way to linearlize the maximization of l1 norm of x, so  it seems that your solution does it. However, maximizing l1 norm is actually maximizing convex function, then how can i linearize such task?

Comment: You can model this case by adding two variable vectors $e^+$ and $e^-$.
The model would be:
$\max e^+ + e^-$ subject to $x \in C$ and $e^+ \leq x$, $e^- \leq -x$, $e^+ - e^- = x$

Comment: And how exactly the constraints will be changed?

Comment: Just as E. Tucker has explained below...

Comment: but what has been suggest wouldnt solve the problem, as i have tried even using MATLAB (CVX to be specific)

Comment: The problem here is that when applying these contraints, one end up with having unbounded feasible region!

Comment: Are you sure that your set $C$ is a polytope, that is, a closed convex set? Maybe the problem is unbounded because the region $C$ has an extreme ray... Can you explain how you define $C$?

Comment: I define $C$ to be a level set of a convex function, i.e. $\left\lbrace x \mid f(x) \leq a \right\rbrace$ for some constant $a > 0$. $C$ is compact and convex, it's not necessarily a polytope, it can be an ellipsoid or any convex body!

Comment: Sorry, I got a little confused... actually the constraints are not right. if $x=10$, there is no way $e^- \leq -10$... However I guess the ones from Tucker are also wrong since if $x= 10$ one may have $t^+ = 10000$ and $t^- = 9990$ (the unboundedness comes from here)... 

However you should check still check if $C$ is a closed set... say for example that $f(x) = x^2$, then obviously $\max |x|$ is unbounded...

Comment: Please take a look at the last session of this reference: http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/absolute.htm
This should work for you.

Comment: The set $C$ is closed and compact, as for your example the set would be represented by C = [-1,1]. I know that the constraints are wrong. However i am trying to change them in a way such that they can work. Do you know any sources for linearizing maximization over l1 norm?

Comment: I will look into that. Thanks!